# using tor with scrapy framework

Tags: python, scrapy, tor

I am trying to crawl website, which is sophisticated enough to stop bots, I mean it is permitting only a few requests, after that Scrapy hangs.

Question 1: is there a way, if Scrapy hangs I can restart my crawling process from the same point.
To get rid of this problem, I wrote my settings file like this

```
BOT_NAME = 'MOZILLA'
BOT_VERSION = '7.0'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['yp.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'yp.spiders'
DEFAULT_ITEM_CLASS = 'yp.items.YpItem'
USER_AGENT = '%s/%s' % (BOT_NAME, BOT_VERSION)

DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0.25
DUPEFILTER=True
COOKIES_ENABLED=False
RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY=True
SCHEDULER_ORDER='BFO'
```

This is my program:

```
class ypSpider(CrawlSpider):

   name = "yp"


   start_urls = [
       SOME URL

   ]
   rules=(
      #These are some rules
   )
   def parse_item(self, response):
   ####################################################################
   #cleaning the html page by removing scripts html tags    
   #######################################################
   hxs=HtmlXPathSelector(response)
```

The question is where I could write the http proxies and shall i have to import any tor related classes, I am new to Scrapy because of this group I learned so much, Now I am trying to learn "how to use ip rotation or tor'

As one of our member suggested, I started tor and I set HTTP_PROXY to

```
set http_proxy=http://localhost:8118
```

but it is throwing some errors,

```
failure with no frames>: class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError'   Connection was refused by other side 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

So i changed http_proxy to

```
set http_proxy=http://localhost:9051
```

Now the error is

```
failure with no frames>: class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone' connection was closed cleanly.
```

I checked firefox network settings, there I couldn't see any http proxies but instead of that Its using SOCKSV5, there it is showing 127.0.0.1:9051. (before TOR it works with no proxies)Please help me I am still not understanding how to use TOR through Scrapy.
Which bundle of TOR I am supposed to use and how?
I hope that both of my questions will be resolved

1. If a scrapy crawler hangs for some reason (Connection failure), I would like to resume the service from there itself
2. How to use rotating IPs in Scrapy

Comment: Have you tried setting the user-agent string to something more convincing than `MOZILLA/7.0`? Try using the full user-agent string of your own browser: http://httpbin.org/user-agent

Answer (score 4):

TOR by itself is not an http proxy, the port 8118 and the connection refused error suggest that you don't have privoxy[1] running properly. Try setting up privoxy correctly and then try again using the environment variable `http_proxy=http://localhost:8118`.

I have done crawling through TOR using privoxy with scrapy successfully.

[1] http://www.privoxy.org/

Comment: Hi Rho

Can you please share here your experience and source code? That could be very interesting for us.

Thank you in advance

Comment: @imx51 there is not too much to share about using TOR as proxy. You just have to set the environment variable and that's all.